# maven war plugin put my resources in war root directory

Tags: maven, war, maven-war-plugin

I don't understand why when I put the `webResources` entry in the `maven-war-plugin`, the resources are placed in the war root directory. I think it should put only in `WEB-INF/classes`. 
This is my `maven-war-plugin` configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <!-- <configuration> <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> </configuration> -->
    <configuration>
       <webResources>
            <resource>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>dbre.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I delete `<webResources>` entry, only default `src/main/resources` files are copied to `WEB-INF/classes` but isn't in root war directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. Quoting [`maven-war-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) documentation:

> The WAR Plugin is also capable of including resources not found in the default resource directory through the webResources parameter.
>   ...
>   `external-resource2.jpg` and `image2` are copied to the root of the WAR, preserving the directory structure.

And later:

> By default web resources are copied to the root of the WAR

If you want to override the default target path, you can specify the `<targetPath>` attribute. For example, if you want the web resources to be located inside `WEB-INF`, you would configure the plugin like this:

```xml
<webResources>
  <resource>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>dbre.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
  </resource>
</webResources>
```